# Setup Ethereum-Wallet as geth RPC

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I develop a dapp with truffle.js and wish to deploy to the live network. I have the Ethereum Wallet already installed (mac osx), and I'm pretty sure it runs on top of geth - am I correct? Anyway, does it act as an RPC server as well? I don't want to install a standalone geth and start moving ether around if I already have a geth running the Ethereum-Wallet. I couldnt find any where in the GUI to config the RPC, nor is it enabled by default (tried to truffle migrate to 127.0.0.1:8545, it says it can't find an RPC server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

geth automatically started by Ethereum-Wallet will not expose the RPC port.

You have two possibilities:

1/ manually start geth with rpc parameters before starting Ethereum Wallet. On Mac OS, you can find the geth executable in the subfolder of EthereumWallet.app.

2/ After starating Ethereum-Wallet, call `geth attach` and activate the RPC API via geth's console (`admin.startRPC()`).